How to deal with PhD loneliness coming from undergrad?
I've just started a PhD and the socialising is quite a lot different to what I expected. I live alone and don't have any close friends or family nearby. Most of my social interaction is with my supervisor. Occasionally I meet other PhD students once or twice a month, but this is normally to work together on something. The societies/socials at my uni are all undergrad orientated as well. All the PhD students that I've met have families or relationships.
The main thing is that I feel like I don't have any friends I can socialise casually with. Therefore, I don't have much of a personal life outside my PhD, - I enjoy researching but probably not enough to do it 24/7 for several years.
Has anyone else experienced this or something similar? Any advice would be much appreciated.

Well, what sorts of things do you like to do? Go find people - any people - who do that sort of thing. Make music, rock climb, bird watch, garden, play bridge, ... If not within official university groups there will still be people in the area who do things and groups to go do them with.

Volunteer at a community garden or retirement home, see which of the myriad clubs available sound interesting and jump in, learn to play a musical instrument, join an intramural sports team, go hiking with others, and so on. Undergrads are people too. Whatever you do, step away from phones and computers. What are some things you’ve already tried?

To continue suggestions by @Jon Custer, what type of exercise/sports do you participate in (jogging, tennis, ping pong, basketball, dancing, yoga, etc.) and what are your hobbies (chess, painting, gaming, cooking, reading certain types of novels, etc.)? I suspect you met many people through these activities as an undergraduate, but maybe being busier as a graduate student you've eliminated some of these activities? Also, restricting yourself to other Ph.D. students is probably a mistake.

There are lots of apps that are for dating that also offer a "find a friend" option, you could try those.

Ultimately this is not an Academia question - anyone moving somewhere else has this issue. Not sure if Interpersonal SE is appropriate or not.

Making friends as an adult is hard because everyone else around you who's been in that town for a while already has a life.
What's worked well for my wife and I over several moves as adults is to find communities of like-minded people who meet up to do their thing. For me, that means that many of my friends are those who, like me, show up at the weekend bike rides I tend to go to -- you get to talk to a lot of people if you ride in a group for 4-5 hours every Saturday and occasionally during the week. The other group of friends I have are people I met at mountaineering happy hours and with whom I ended up spending whole days up in the mountains. For my wife, her friends tend to come from either a knitting group that meets once a week for a couple of hours at one of the local breweries, or people from her running group.
Point being: People often have regular get-togethers to talk about or do the thing they enjoy. Figure out what it is you enjoy, and look around where these people meet.

Your department probably has a bulletin board. It may have a coffee lounge. You can capitalize on these.
If you participate in any sports you can post a note asking for others to participate. In my case, there was a weekly department softball game, very informal. Racquetball, tennis? Soccer/futbol? I had a few folks, including some faculty, who took fifty mile bike rides frequently. Various things. A bridge (card game) club is a possibility. A daily lunch break works. Weekly movies. Current event discussion groups (a bit risky). Lots of things. Encourage others that you meet to make suggestions.
Many universities have an indoor running track that is open for casual use in off hours, even for easy jogging.
If you see a discussion in the coffee room you can sit in provided it isn't obviously private (unlikely). You can be passive for a while but introduce yourself, at least. Let things grow naturally.
Note that some of these things have the added benefit of being aerobic, which is a good thing for your health, both physical and mental.

Look outside your academic program for connections with people.
Some universities have graduate student groups for socializing.
Or, there may be clubs at the university you might like (such as chess, dancing, sports).
See if there is an involvement fair.
Also, look outside the university.
A community of faith (or non-faith community such as secular/humanistic groups) is a often a good place to meet people.
Or, clubs for activates you like.
Or, volunteer somewhere like a soup kitchen, Habitat for Humanity, nature center or similar civic type group.
Lastly, consider therapy.
Many universities have resources for students you may not know about.

Does your department have talks/seminars you could attend in person? Do other departments at your university? Go in person and then ask people to grab a coffee afterwards.
You don’t have to limit your seminar attendance or your friends to your own department. Any talk or program aimed at research is going to be mostly aimed at grad students. Create a “PhD students” group text for anyone you meet. Get in the habit of letting people know when you see an interesting talk and/or when you might be working in the library, they will start to do the same.
